# Elegant way for passing list to function as input arguments with incomplete list/missing list entries

Tags: python, list, function, parameters, default

I'm writing a program (see below) where the user can set parameters x[0] and x[1]. Sometimes the user is not setting x[1] as it's not always needed (tested with #x[1]=2). If x[1] is not set, I want the function to use the default b=5 as value.
When testing, as expected, when function1 is called, it gives me an error saying x[1] is missing. I tried a lot playing aroung with "=None" etc, but can't get it to recognize x[1] is non-existing and using b=5 as default.

Anyone knows a elegant pythonian way to implement this? (I guess there's a simple way that slipped my tired mind or I, as beginner, simply don'T know up to now :)

Thx, Toby

```
def function1(a, b=5):
    print(a)
    print(b)

x={}
x[0]=1
#x[1]=2

function1(x[0],x[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function definition can stay the same:

```
def function1(a, b=5):
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Your way of calling the function needs to change.

For positional arguments don't use a dict `{}`, use a list `[]`:

```
x = [1, 2]
function1(*x)     # prints 1 & 2

x = [1]
function1(*x)     # prints 1 & 5
```

For named arguments use a dict (but then you have to call the values `a` and `b`, like the function does):

```
x = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
function1(**x)     # prints 1 & 2

x = {"a": 1}
function1(**x)     # prints 1 & 5
```

When used in a function call, the `*` operator unpacks lists, and the `**` operators unpacks dicts into the function's arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This helps me a lot!
How would I handle the case, if my function has 3 input variables but the user only defines Var1 and Var3 with the middle one (Var2) missing?

Comment: @canedha In this case you need to use the approach that is based on named arguments. Positional parameters can't have "holes".

Comment: and how would I call the function using the named arguments? don't they have to be in the correct order? do you maybe have a good link where that is explained? :) Thx for your help, it's really appreciated!

Comment: @canedha I've explained it in my answer, maybe you want to read it again? I think you can find out if order matters or not very quickly with an experiment.

Comment: ok, I will give it a try :) btw. I'm not lazy testing things out, the reason I asked that specific is that I have very limited time due to small children. Again big thanks for your help! Really appreciated it :)

Comment: @canedha I'm not saying you are. I am just convinced that details you have figured out on your own stick better in memory than details you have been told by others.